# Can't seem to apply classList.toggle in a loop

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm currently trying to switch between images. I have a couple of images stacked on top of each other and initially all of them have a   `display:none;`. I want when I click a button a random image to appear on the screen. Selected every picture with `querySelectorAll`, made a random number generator and my goal was to iterate through them, and the number which is picked at the moment would signify which picture I was going to make visible. The problem is that in the console I can see that it's trying to toggle the class but nothing happens

Code for reference:

```
var button = document.querySelector(".btn-roll");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var images = document.querySelectorAll(".dice");
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  var number =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 0);
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[number].classList.toggle("Appear");
  }
})
```

CSS for reference:

```
.dice {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 178px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
  display: none;
}

.Appear {
  display:block;
}
```

Additionally if there's something wrong with my for loop I tried adding all the images in an array and iterating through it as well, with no success as well.

Comment: Your code makes no sense, you're iterating from 0 to images length, and each time trying to access the same item (the last random number generated). You're also adding that `number` variable globally since you didn't declare it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to fix:

- `number` is not defined before it is used
- You are calculating number 6 times, only needs to happen once.
- You are calling `toggle` but not telling it if it should toggle off or on (Does not work in IE11)
- You are always just toggeling `number` and not the entire list.

```js
var button = document.querySelector(".btn-roll");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var images = document.querySelectorAll(".dice");
  var number =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 0);

  for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].classList.toggle("Appear", i === number);
  }
})
```

```css
.dice {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 178px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
  display: none;
}

.Appear {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-roll">Roll</button>
<div class="dice">1</div>
<div class="dice">2</div>
<div class="dice">3</div>
<div class="dice">4</div>
<div class="dice">5</div>
<div class="dice">6</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much, that solved my problem, now I know how to select a specific item, cheers!